# SQL in memory table keeps growing although its been emptied out

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table that resides in memory. It is memory optimized and does not have any other settings on it. I basically use this table to cache some information for quick access every 15 minutes or so. The problem I have that even though I delete all of the data from it on a schedule it does not seem to release the RAM. It keeps growing by the amount of data added although the old data has been deleted.

Any idea what i need to do to prevent its footprint from exploding?

Answer (score 0):

SQL will use all available RAM on the system by design. It will keep growing until it has used everything, it's why SQL is meant to be the only thing installed on the server. I don't think there is any way to stop it.

Comment: The issue is that SQL is telling me that the memory footprint of the In RAM table is 10 gigs when there are no rows in the table. I looked up garbage collection for in RAM sql and Microsoft claims it is very aggressive. Needles to say I am very confused.

Comment: Is it slowing the system down? Are you running out of memory? Are there any errors? A lot of people only start looking at RAM usage when they have a problem. Where are you seeing the information that SQL is taking up 10GB?

Comment: I get this information by querying: select * from sys.dm_db_xtp_table_memory_stats  . I don't have RAM issues right now. but i've read that garbage collection is supposed to be aggressive and it does not seem to be. for example it says that the in memory table has 19GB allocated to it and that its using 8 GB but the table is empty. Thats concerning me.

Answer (score 0):

By default, SQL Server will use as much RAM as it can. You can specify hard limits by configuring the minimum memory and maximum memory that SQL Server can use in MB. SQL Server will always allocate the minimum memory, but it will continue to allocate until it reaches the maximum limit configured.

Once it reaches the limit, it will decide what should stay in memory and what should go. While it will start evicting items internally, it will not reduce it's allocated footprint. So if you set your min limit to 1 GB and max limit to 10 GB, it will start at 1 GB and work its way up to 10 GB. Once it reaches 10 GB, it will stay there, but it may only be using 5 GB internally. There are monitoring tools and other queries out there that can tell you how much memory SQL Server is actively using out of the total it has allocated from the OS. Those can be two very different numbers.

Keep in mind that these values are **not** limited to memory optimized tables--they affect all of SQL Server. If you have the RAM, use it!

```
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'show advanced options', N'1'  RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'min server memory (MB)', N'1024' -- 1 GB
GO
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'max server memory (MB)', N'16384' -- 16 GB
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
EXEC sys.sp_configure N'show advanced options', N'0'  RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

Comment: When i query: select * from sys.dm_db_xtp_table_memory_stats it tells me that the memmory alocated for the table is 18 GB and that the memory used by the tables is 8 gigs. The issue i have is that the table is empty. I am new to in memory tables and I am worried this will turn into a problem because the RAM does not seem to be getting released.